# Jammy in KDE / Kubuntu does not seem to have a GUI to manually save sessions

Tags: kubuntu, kde, session, documentation

In 20.04, I could turn on manual sessions in settings and use the launcher to leave, I was given an option to my save session.  In Jammy / 22.04 with manual sessions turned on, I see no such option.  I'm running Ubuntu with a KDE desktop added.  Am I missing some GUI feature or has KDE dropped this (which makes no sense)?

Answer (score 2):

In my installation, after selecting "Restore manually saved session" and clicking "Apply", you first have to restart the system before the option "Save Session" is shown in "Leave".